# IONIC2 RC5: Sliders slider.getSlider() return undefined

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am using Slider, after update to RC5 the method getSlider for slider componet return undefined, How I can fix this?

The documentation says "ion-slides, getSlider() has been removed. Please use the properties and methods on the instance of ion-slides instead.", Which property can replace this?

Why I need it ?, I am using it to update the slider page content after the user slide left or right.

```
let swiper = slider.getSlider();       
 setTimeout(() => {
    swiper.update();
    swiper.init();
  });
```

Comment: Have you tried using slider.update() instead of swiper.update?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on where you are calling the `getSlider()` method. As far as I know there is a little issue with this method and you should call it inside a `ionViewDidEnter` hook and even inside a setTimeout:

```
ionViewDidEnter() {      
   setTimeout(() => {
      let swiper = slider.getSlider();
      swiper.update();
      swiper.init();
   });
}
```

Comment: slider.getSlider() always return undefined.